# How can I add XElement iterating elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, iteration, xelement

This is my code:

```
var xml = new XElement("test", new[] {
    new XElement("group", new[] {
        new XElement("date", dateNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    }),

    new XElement("users", new[] {
        foreach(var item in in PlaceHolderCustom.Controls)
        {
            new XElement("nome", ((TextBox)item.FindControl("myTextBox")).Text)
        }
    })
});
```

I'd like to set in the xml some fixed fields (within the element "group") and some that would iterate across a placeholder. But the syntax seems to be wrong when I try to add a new "iterating" list.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq `.Select` to perform the `foreach`. Also when you create the array the `new [] {}` syntax is valid only for `new string[]`. In your case use:

- `new XElement[] {}`
- Or because the method gets a `params object[]` you can just give each `new XElement` independently without wrapping with an array

So showing both ways of passing the collection of `XElements`:

```
var xml = new XElement("test",
    new XElement("group", new XElement[] {
        new XElement("date", dateNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    }),
    new XElement("users", PlaceHolderCustom.Control.Select(item =>
        new XElement("nome", ((TextBox)item.FindControl("myTextBox")).Text)).ToArray())
);
```